# Storing bounding box in database (mariaDB)?

Tags: postgresql, mysql, mariadb

Is there a bounding box type or a nearest equivalent for specifying a column the will store an extent (SE-NW) and how would I then query the database to find entries where a point exists within it?

My use case is that I am wanting to create a table that will list a collection of GPX files covering different areas and I want to be able to search for entries that cover a given point.

My current question is for MariaDB, but I am also evaluating Postresql+Postgis for our environment.

Comment: I would suggest to read something about MariaDB and spatial from the web and make more focused questions after that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See postgreSQL geometric Type:
https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/datatype-geometric.html

For bounding box, you can use "**box**" type.

Some Postgis functions return BBOX, like this aggregate:
https://postgis.net/docs/ST_Extent.html

For intersection, you can use Postgis function like ST_Intersects:
https://postgis.net/docs/ST_Intersects.html